# OpenVPN-AS not starting

Tags: linux, openvpn, openvz

I have been trying to get an OpenVPN Access server running but I am having a lot of trouble.

I have a host node running Proxmox and I would like an OpenVZ container to run the server.

I have gone through [this guide](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/186-how-to-run-access-server-on-a-vps-container.html) but I still receive the following errors when starting the server.

```
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['iptables_openvpn'])
Service deferred error: IPTablesServiceBase: failed to run iptables-restore [status=1]: ['iptables-restore: line 35 failed']: internet/defer:323,sagent/ipts:119,sagent/ipts:46,util/mycprof:11,<string>:1,sagent/sagent_entry:14,sagent/sagent_entry:11,util/daemon:28,util/daemon:69,application/app:423,scripts/_twistd_unix:202,application/app:445,application/app:348,internet/base:1166,internet/base:1178,internet/epollreactor:194,python/log:85,python/log:70,python/context:59,python/context:37,internet/epollreactor:223,internet/posixbase:191,internet/process:260,internet/process:762,internet/process:775,internet/_baseprocess:60,svc/pp:116,svc/svcnotify:32,internet/defer:238,internet/defer:307,internet/defer:323,sagent/ipts:119,sagent/ipts:46,util/error:60,util/error:43
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_live', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['user', 'iptables_live', 'iptables_openvpn'])
service failed to start due to unresolved dependencies: set(['iptables_live', 'iptables_openvpn'])
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenVPN-AS installer creates some iptables rules automatically during the install process.   The error you're seeing looks like it may not be able to perform these changes, which could be for a variety of reasons. First, are you installing from an account with permissions to modify iptables rules?  Second, I'm not familiar enough with OpenVZ containers enough to know if they run either AppArmor or SELinux by default, or might have some other security layer that's interfering with the install or service start.

If you've paid even the base $50 minimum for the lowest-cost AS license, OpenVPN support is extremely helpful with troubleshooting these types of issues -- may be worth a ticket.

As an aside, OpenVPN works really well for us on stock Ubuntu (10.04, 12.04) running as a KVM guest.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am installing with the root account on the OpenVZ container. Still no luck.

Comment: Are you able to manually edit iptables rules?  Like in this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/298921/openvpn-routing-for-openvz-containers?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ended up just rebooting the host (I was trying to avoid this) and it looks like it's all working now.

Comment: Well, the server now starts up alright but I am having trouble connecting to it. The client will start to connect but ends up just disconnecting moments later. I also get this in the admin are of the access server.

openvpn x.x.x.x:65279 5.5.8.2 4.07KB 4.97KB 0:00:09 -

Comment: What kind of client are you connecting from?  If it's the Windows GUI client, make sure you're using the most recent version (or the version available on your OpenVPN-AS server by logging in at https://[your_internal_ip]:943/). If it's an iOS (or possibly Mac) client, make sure to add a line reading `pull` to the auto-generated config file you downloaded before you import it.

Comment: Re-installed the client, all good! Thanks so much for your help!